# Get PID of some running task

Tags: java, pid

I need to get process ID of running task. I am not sure why below code is failing. It is going unresponsive everytime i run the code as standalone.

```
 Map<String,String> checkRunningProcess(){
        Map<String,String>processPid = new HashMap<String,String>();
        try{
            String line,processName;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh"); 
            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));


            while((line = input.readLine())!=null){
                String all[] = line.split(",");
                all[0] = all[0].replace("\"","");
                all[1] = all[1].replace("\"", "");
                //System.out.println(all[0]+all[1]);

                  processPid.put(all[0],all[1]);
            }

        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return processPid;
    }
```

Comment: You should run the code using a debugger and see what output you are getting from the provess.  From that you can narrow down which of the possible problems this could be.

Comment: Someone asked in a (non-)answer what the OS and Java versions are.   The OS is clearly Windows, but you could tell us what the Java version is.  (I don't actually think it is relevant ... but someone does.)

Comment: How do you run it? When I ran your method from a main method, it simply worked fine.

Comment: Also, can you manually run the command via the command line console?

Comment: I wonder if on some versions of Windows, `tasklist.exe` outputs to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: Do you want the PID of the current running Java application?